# Installer on 32-bit system saves files to virtual store in windows 10

Tags: visual-studio-2012, windows-installer, windows-10, 32-bit, virtualstore

I’ve updated an old installer to work on Windows 10. The program installs correctly on a 64-bit system but not on 32-bit.  The files are ending up in “C:\users\etc….\appdata\local\virtual store” instead of the path I specified. Does anyone know why this is happening?

Comment: Yes. You're not running the installer as an administrator, and non-admins can no longer write to the *Program Files* or Windows directories. For applications without a manifest, Windows virtualizes those write requests to the location you specified. That's been the case since Windows Vista was released.

Comment: I even tried as an administrator still i face the same problem.